# Best practice to pass many variables

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class `Character`: it holds many `private` variables such as `positionX, PositionY, Atk, Def, Agi, Velocity` and  have to pass it to a function which processes and changes this `Character` variables.
Since it has so many variables, how do I pass these variables? Should I make getter and setter for each variable? What is the best practice regarding this?

I'm thinking about making a `struct` class that holds all those variables, so I can just pass that `struct` class, but I don't know if it's a good practice.

Comment: I'll vote for closing of this question as too broad, because there are lots of different approaches, but the simplest is --- why not make this function a member function of `Character` class?

Comment: `Character` is already a class. Why make `struct` then?

Comment: Make const getters in your class and pass an object of your class wherever your want.

Comment: because this `Character` class holds too many variable and making a getter setter for each variable is just seems bad to me.

Comment: BTW, it seems you should have sub-struct as `PositionX` and `PositionY` can be merged into `Position` and same for some other characteristics of your Character.

Comment: Well, if they are private and you must change or read them individually then you have no choice but to write getters and possibly setters. You are right that this kind of "boiler plate" code is a nuisance (which has been addressed to a degree in C#).-- But if, on the other hand, multiple private member variables change "atomically" with a single state change (and if they do not have an individual meaning outside the class), then at least setters would actually be bad (e.g. x,y,z coordinates in a moving object which can not "jump" but just reacts to outside forces).

Comment: The case is i have a seperate `Command` class that handles `Character` action, the reason i make a seperate class is that so i can use it if i have more than one `Character` but has their own unique `Command`. i hope i'm not confusing you guys, sorry. EDIT: oops, i replied the wrong thread.

Comment: A fairly popular practice is to use "Object-Oriented Programming" and perform computations in "member functions".

Answer (score 5):

If you pass just the struct it will be copied. Good practice is to either pass it in as a reference or as a const reference, or even as a shared_ptr

```
void foo(const MyStruct& ms);
void foo(MyStruct& ms);
void foo(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> ms);
```

Comment: When would one pass an `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Well you might pass `const std::shared_ptr &` esp. if `foo` needs to make some copies of the `shared_ptr`. But yeah passing `std::shared_ptr` by value is typically just wasteful.

Comment: Hi there, do you happen to have a copy of the screenshot you posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24968/unusual-spacing-in-the-description-text-of-careers)?

Answer (score 2):

If your function modifies private variables, then the function should probably be a member function.

If that is not appropriate, then you could declare the function a friend of the class.

If you have lots of functions that can't be members but need to access the member variables, and you don't need the encapsulation, then consider making the members public.

Comment: This is particularly true for Java, but C++ also has freestanding friend functions.

Comment: The case is i have a seperate `Command` class that handles `Character` action, the reason i make a seperate class is that so i can use it if i have more than one `Character` but has their own unique `Command`. i hope i'm not confusing you guys, sorry.

Comment: Could you elaborate on declare the function a friend of the class??

Comment: @user3189174 you can use a friend declaration to do that. You can look up the syntax from the book that you're using to study c++.